# Error: Could not find or load main class при использовании WebSpere

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, websphere

Мавен-проект. Был изначально сделан с использованием Tomcat - всё замечательно работало. Получил задание запустить через WebSphere.

Скачал другую версию Eclipse, cоздал новый проект на основе прошлого, но каждый раз, когда пытаюсь запустить, получаю следующую ошибку:

**Error: Could not find or load main class Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271\bin;;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin;D:\Eclipse 2019\eclipse;.;**

Не могу даже предположить, чем может вызвана ошибка. Jdk в istalled jres указан, мавен собирает приложение успешно, но при запуске на сервере всегда вот так.

[image: архитектрура проекта]

[image: здесь сервер не выбирается]

[image: хотя здесь присутствует]
[image: и здесь]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какой тип `Run Configuration` используете? Судя по ошибке - `Java Application`, а нужно вам `Generic Server` или `Generic Server(external)` или специфичный для WebSphere, если устанавливали плагины. В любом случае в вопросе нужно добавить информацию о том, как запускаете.

Comment: Вы правы, зашёл в run configuration, а там сервер не выбирается, несмотря на то, что в списке серверов существует. Не подскажете, как это возможно исправить?

Comment: Нужно использовать плагин. Какой точно сейчас актуален - не скажу, но этот выглядит подходящим на первый взгляд https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-liberty-developer-tools

Comment: К сожалению, перебрал несколько плагинов (учитывая указанный Вами), но сервер выбрать всё равно не удаётся.

Comment: Сервер нужно создать в `Preferences -> Servers -> Runtime Environment -> Add`. Важно создать именно websphere, а чтоб он был доступен нужен плагин.

Comment: Прямо из окна добавления сервера можно скачать плагин для webshere

Comment: Прикрепил ещё один скриншот. В Runtime Environment сервер существует, но при выборе run configuration он не предлагается как опция

Comment: Нужно открыть `Window -> Show Views -> Others -> Servers` и там создать.

Comment: На одном из скриншотов видно, что сервер там уже существует
С созданием проблем не возникает, но в run configuration он не предлагается как опция